# How to match string in Drools using regexp with parameters?

Tags: java, regex, drools, rules

I want to use the in build keyword matches at the when part of drools to match a string.

e.g.

```
rule "test"
when Foo( fooid : id )
     Bar( barid : id, barid not matches "ID=" + fooid + ", " + name )
then ...
```

It doesnt seem to work because it is complaining about "ID=" + fooid + ", " + name.

But if I remove all the parameters, it runs i.e. leaving only "ID="

So the problem seems to be at how you include more parameters in the matching pattern, how would you solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you save both fooid, barid before checking on the rules. Not sure if it's possible, you may give it a try.

```
string fooid = Food id // use correct syntax
string barid = Bar id // use correct syntax
string checkstring = "ID=" + fooid + "," + name

rule "test"  
    when   
        barid: String(this not matches "(?i)." + checkstring)  
    then  
        System.out.println(checkstring);  
    end
```

**notes:**

(?i) - ignore case

Answer (score 0):

rule "PuneUser_Rule"

```
no-loop true
ruleflow-group "EvalLoopcondition"
when
    m:HelloProcessModel(userlocation in ("PuneUser"), count < 4)
then
    m.setLoopcondition(6);update(m);
```

end

Here we check the rule, if PuneUser and count is less than 4 then loop will run from count till loopcondition that is till 6 .

This rule will be follwed only when you are checking the string is PuneUser or not